# magento 2 : How to create module in pwa studio

Tags: magento2, plugin, pwa, pwa-studio

Regarding pwa module development

How to create module in pwa studio?

how we can apply current custom magento plugin in pwa ??

Answer (score 0):

The backend remains the same for headless Magento applications using PWA studio. Existing and custom Magento plugins (if you are indeed referring to these plugins https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/plugins/) will still execute - you just need to make sure the frontend is still triggering the logic required.